# How to import javascript export file generated from the webpack.config?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, npm, webpack

#### Problem description

I need to set the DEV or Production environment so I can test API's either locally or get them ready for production.

ie: Either use `http://localhost/api/app/login` or `/api/app/login`

Now I was able to accomplish this by attaching NODE_ENV variables to my npm scripts in the package.json and a couple of lines of code in my webpack.config as so:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --history-api-fallback",
    "prod": "NODE_ENV=production webpack-dev-server -p",
```

webpack.config

```
const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV;
....
new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: "static" }])
```

^ that will create an env I can use in my `services/api.js` file. **Now my Problem** is that my Jest tests will fail every time because `env` is undefined.

### Attempted solution - need help

So now instead what I'm trying to do is use node to actually generate a Javascript file that I can actually import directly into my `services/api.js` that way I avoid the undefined `env` error in testing.

**I'm able to create a Javascript file with the following updates to my webpack.config**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const webpack = require('webpack')
const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV;

// fs.writeFileSync('src/consts/env.txt', environment);

const stream = fs.createWriteStream("src/consts/endpoints.js");
stream.once('open', function(fd) {
  stream.write('export const environment = () => "'+environment+'"');
  stream.end();
});
```

**The file it created (src/consts/endpoints.js):**

```
export const environment = () => "development"
```

I've also tried this way:

```
export const environment = "development"
```

**Now my updated** `services/api.js`

```
import axios from 'axios'
import environment from '../consts/endpoints'
console.log('api.js environment:', environment);
```

**However environment is undefined when I check out localhost.**
[image]

---

How can I fix this problem? Is it a race condition? Is there another way to generate the file I need to import?

I tried to generate a .txt file however I can't import that file locally, can only do it in the cloud.

### Full webpack.config file

```
const fs = require('fs');
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");
const dist = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
const src = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");
const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV;

// fs.writeFileSync('src/consts/env.txt', environment);

const stream = fs.createWriteStream("src/services/environment.js");
stream.once('open', function(fd) {
  stream.write('export const environment = "'+environment+'"');
  stream.end();
});

module.exports = {
  context: src,
  entry: [
    "./index.js"
  ],
  output: {
    path: dist,
    filename: "manage2.bundle.js",
    publicPath: '/static/',
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallbackLoader: "style-loader",
          loader: ["css-loader", "sass-loader"],
          publicPath: dist
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    hot: false,
    quiet: true,
    publicPath: "",
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    compress: true,
    stats: "errors-only",
    open: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "index.html"
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: "manage2.css",
      disable: false,
      allChunks: true
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: "static" }])
  ]
};
// new webpack.DefinePlugin({ env: JSON.stringify(environment) })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Figured it out!

I was importing the file incorrectly.

So from **webpack.config**

```
const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV;

const stream = fs.createWriteStream("src/services/environment.js");
stream.once('open', function(fd) {
  stream.write('const env = "'+environment+'"\n');
  stream.write('export default env');
  stream.end();
});
```

^ That generates this file (**src/services/environment.js**) which contains:

```
const env = "development"
export default env
```

Finally in my **services/api.js** file I can use the import statement the way I wanted, I was missing the `export default` from above.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import endpoints from './endpoints'
import env from './environment'

const api = endpoints(env);
console.log('api', api);

const log = (method, err) => {
    console.error(`%c${method}`, 'background: #393939; color: #F25A43', err);
    return err;
};

export const userLogin = (username, password) => {
    const post_data = { username, password };
    return axios.post(api.login, post_data)
        .then(res => res)
        .catch((err) => log('api.userLogin', err));
};
```

And in my package.json I can change the ENV var to spit out `"development"` or `"production"`.

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --history-api-fallback",
    "prod": "NODE_ENV=production webpack-dev-server -p",
```

Comment: If someone marks down a question or answer then it should be mandatory that they enter a comment to say why.  I cannot see what is wrong with this question or answer.  I am going to vote these up to spite that person that did.